# Microsoft Azure Export SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have a problem exporting the database from MS Azure Web Panel. I have a premium account and it says that Storage is not supported for such type of accounts. Now, is it possible to export it in some way or I have to change my account type first?

I have SQL server logins too, but I can't seem to connect to the database via MS SQL Server Manager tool. I copy the server name from the Azure Panel and I use these logins, but it says that server is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a premium account and it says that Storage is not supported for
> such type of accounts. Now, is it possible to export it in some way or
> I have to change my account type first?

By `Premium`, I am assuming you mean a `Premium LRS` kind of Storage Account which only supports `Page Blobs`.

Azure SQL Database export to storage accounts doesn't support `Premium` storage accounts.

From the [`documentation link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export):(Emphasis mine on storage account type)

> An Azure subscription.
>
> An Azure SQL Database.
>
> An **Azure Standard Storage account** with a blob container to store the BACPAC in standard storage.

So, you would need to create a new `Standard` storage account and use that for backing up your SQL Database.

Comment: Is there any other way to connect to that DB? I am using a PHP application and it connects to it using another hostname, but I can't connect to it via SQL Server Management Studio either.

Comment: [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms) shows how to connect to an Azure SQL database using SQL Server Management Studio, please refer to it.